# How to lookup in column and return the column letter (not full address or column number) using single function?

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

When using `hlookup()`, it will return the col number so need another function to convert to the letter.

Also when using `address()`, it will return the full address. In fact, I want just the letter. For example: just return "H", not "H23", I have to add another function like **`regexextract(string,"\D+")`**

I'm just curious if there is built-in function get the column letter directly without any additional function.

Answer (score 1):

there is **`CELL`** function:

```
=CELL("col", C2)
```

[image]

which returns column as number but combined with **`CHAR`** you can convert number back to letter when you add 64

```
=CHAR(CELL("col", C1)+64)
```

[image: 0]

or:

```
=CHAR(MATCH("find header", 1:1, 0)+64)
```

which is shorter than regexing `ADDRESS` but works only for A-Z columns (eg. not AA and onwards)

so when creating indirect array reference it usually goes like:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, 3)&":"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, 3), 1, )))
```

or shorter if possible:

```
=INDIRECT("C2:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, 3), 1, )))
```

to return range **C2:C**

ofc. instead of `3` in `ADDRESS` you will have something like `=MATCH("header", 1:1, 0)`)